# ClothFX animation not working

Tags: animation, collision

I'm not familiar with animation, so I'm betting it's something simple. I'm trying to do a simple cloth collision with ClothFx Haddon and it animates fine with the timeline, but will not render. I've searched and the only two things I've found that could cause this is either a subsurf modifier that has not been applied or the subsurf modifier not below the cloth modifier. I tried both of those and they didn't work; the trigger still goes right through the cloth. Any help would be appreciated.  http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=44687

thanks...

Comment: Images showing your cloth and modifier settings would be useful. Also, files uploaded to pasteall are removed after a while, so your question won't have much information in it for future readers to go by. Consider using [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) instead.

Comment: Does it have a solidify modifier? is the cloth solid?

Comment: yes, I applied a solidify modifier.

Comment: here is the file I uploaded to Blender-Exchange [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2394" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2394/)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have your modifiers in the correct order. Had someone help me figure out this order that worked for us.
[image: modifier order]

Answer (score -1):

The solution above is NOT working for me. Im using ClothFX v2 and the right order of the modifiers to get them rendered is as follows:

[image]

So don't forget to order them BEFORE baking and remember, this works with the **VERSION 2** of ClothFX!